# Retrofit Error - Status code 34 in Android Studio

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm trying to get JSON data using Retrofit fromm themoviedb.org api.

I want to get the details of a given movie id.
for example:
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/75780?api_key=XXXXXXX
where the id of the movie is : 75780
& the api_key is my api key.

While in android studio, I have this interface

```
@GET("/3/movie/{movie_id}")
Call<MovieResponse> getMovie(
        @Query("movie_id") long movie_id,
        @Query("api_key") String key
);
```

I suspect that the error is in the @Query!
please tell me how to get data from

/3/movie/{movie_id}?api_key=XXXXXXXXX

I have tried this code

```
   @GET("/3/movie/{id}?apiKey={api_key}")
Call<MovieResponse> getMovie(
        @Path("id") int id,
        @Query("api_key") String key
);
```

Also I tried this code

```
@GET("/3/movie/{id}")
Call<MovieResponse> getMovie(
        @Path("id") int id,
        @Query("api_key") String key
);
```

Nothing is working !! Please help

Comment: 34 is not a valid HTTP status code. How did you get that?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `@Query("movie_id")` with `@Path("movie_id")`. `movie_id` is a path parameter not query. Use integer for `movie_id` instead of long (not to waste memory). Head over [api doc](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-movie-details).